# CRUD PHP y SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

estoy iniciando con PHP, y estoy tratando de hacer un simple CRUD. Tengo la conexión a la base de datos de la siguiente manera y funciona, al final me imprime Que la conexión ha sido exitosa.

```
$serverName = "localhost";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"PDA", "UID"=>"Usuario", "PWD"=>"password", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
$con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if($con){
    echo "Conexion exitosa";
}else{
    echo "Fallo en la conexión";
}
```

El código para el formulario es el siguiente:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h1>CRUD CON PHP Y SQL SERVER</h1>

    <form method="POST" action="formulario.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Cargo</label>
            <input type="text" name="cargo" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba el cargo"><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="Submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-warning" value="INSERTAR DATOS"><br/>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
<br/><br/><br/>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST["insert"])) {
        $cargo = $_POST["cargo"];

    $insertar = "EXECUTE PDA.CREARCARGO '$cargo'";

    $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con, $insertar);


    if($ejecutar){
        echo "<h3>Insertado correctamente</h3>";
    }
}

?>

<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Cargo</td>
            <td>Acción</td>
            <td>Acción</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM PDA.CARGOS";

            $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con, $consulta);

            $i = 0;

            while ($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {
                #$id = $fila["id"];
                $cargo = $fila["cargo"];
                $i++;
            }
        ?>
        <tr align="center">
            <!--<td><?php echo $id;?></td>-->
            <td><?php echo $cargo;?></td>
            <td><a href="formulario.php?editar=<?php echo $id;?>">Editar</a></td>
            <td><a href="formulario.php?borrar=<?php echo $id;?>">Borrar</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Sin embargo me aparece el siguiente error y no me carga los datos en la tabla

Notice: Undefined index: cargo in C:\xampp\htdocs\Conexion_SQL\formulario.php on line 62

Cabe resaltar que estoy utilizando XAMPP

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema sucede porque no encuentra encuentra el índice 'cargo' en el array `$fila` que generas mediante la función `sqlsrv_fetch_array`. Por lo que quizás podría deberse a que el resultado de la `query` es vacío. ¿Podrías comprobrar primero que el resultado contiene alguna columna? Por ejemplo con la función `sqlsrv_has_rows`:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM PDA.CARGOS";

$ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con, $consulta);

if (sqlsrv_has_rows( $ejecutar )) {
      $i = 0;

      while ($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ejecutar, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          #$id = $fila["id"];
          $cargo = $fila["cargo"];
          $i++;
       }
} else {
      $cargo = 'No existen cargos.';
}
```